# can not install Web Essentials 2013 for VS2013

Tags: c#

Am not able to install the Web Essentials 2013 for VS2013

While installing am getting the Installation failed error.

Please can any one help in resolving the issue.

Comment: You need to provide what error you are getting.

Answer (score 9):

You might have installed wrong version. Latest version is for Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC, and if you don't have that, you need to use an older version of Web Essentials.

Here's a link for Web Essentials releases on GitHub, where you can download suitable version: [Web Essentials releases](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/releases)

Comment: I have tried installing from the above mentioned link, but no luck am getting the following error "This extension cannot be installed because the following references are missing:

- VS2013 Update 2 RC"   Even i tried from nuget to download Web Essentials Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC

Comment: Just to clarify, did you try to install [version 1.9](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/releases/tag/v1.9)? There's a discussion on [Web Essentials Q&A section](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361/view/Discussions) which sounds like similar problem, and there the version 1.9 installation has helped.

Comment: Yes, I tried with version 1.9 and it's installed sucessfully.            Thank you so much.. :)